# Making a function to help fault finding

Tags: php, function, reference

OK, so dont laugh.  I have never tried to make my own functions before. I did my research but still came up short. I am trying to make a function that I can insert at various places in my script to check what variables are being used and passed. Simple stuff and I could just cut and paste the code into the pages and be done with with it but I know I can do better than that.  Here is what Ive tried but it keeps telling me its undefined.

```
    function fault(){ 
    $fault ='echo"Fault Finding Pausing for 5 seconds";
   sleep(5);
   var_dump($_POST);
   echo "<br>";
   var_dump($_SESSION);
    }
```

and I call it on my pages with fault(); with no luck.  I may be way off track here. So have at me.

Comment: Far, far easier to use xdebug instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you actually want is a good way to debug your pages. There are lots of third party libraries to do this but what you want is a simple function.

```
function fault() {
    echo "<pre>";
    // Dump GET|POST
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    // Dump SESSION if it is set
    if (isset($_SESSION)) {
        var_dump($_SESSION);
    }
    echo "</pre>";
    // Prevent rest of the script from executing
    exit;
}
```

Put this function in a file called `functions.php`. This is a very basic debugging function. To call it:

```
// At the top of your file
require('functions.php');

// To call your function
fault();
```

Comment: still telling me its undefined.

Comment: @AdrianFischer The function has to be available in the files you call it in. Either use an `include` or define the function in the files.

Comment: doh!  I put the function in the header script which gets called on every script/page....except the script where I tried it which is my inserts script which doesnt need a header. all working now.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: A minor issue. When I run it I get header already called errors.  Ive been through every script and cant for the life of me see where there is html called before the header location.  Took me ages to work out what was going on.  Recoded and fiddled only to realise it was the function file.  Now I know I just ignore it but it had me going for a while.

Comment: Make sure there are now empty lines before your `<?php` tag